# NFS - Combine no_root_squash and squash_all options

Tags: linux, nfs

Is there a way to combine the squash_all and no_root_squash options for NFS? I want non-root local users to use the file permissions of a specific UID (so I do want to squash them) but I do *not* want to squash root.

Yes, I am aware of the security implications. This NFS is running on a Virtual Machine accessible only from the host machine. I need users on the host machine to be able to edit both as a certain UID and as root.

I've tried `no_root_squash` by itself (which results in no squashing at all), `root_squash` by itself (results in only root getting squashed), `all_squash` followed by `no_root_squash` and `no_root_squash` followed by `all_squash` (both result in all getting squashed, including root).

Comment: @roaima I've tried no_root_squash by itself (which results in no squashing at all), root_squash by itself (results in only root getting squashed), all_squash followed by no_root_squash and no_root_squash followed by all_squash (both result in all getting squashed, including root).

Comment: Does not setting different options based on different users help?

Comment: @RamanSailopal how might someone do that, please?

Comment: @RamanSailopal If you're referring to /etc/idmapd.conf, I'm not sure how I'd manage to do that without Kerberos or LDAP.